# Retrieving the DOM view of a webpage in Java not just Source

Tags: java, html, dom

Is it possible to get the Dom view of a page, such as what you see in chrome when you click inspect element, compared to view source. I need to access this through java, and currently i can just get the source.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Would it not be easier to create a browser plugin?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you have to follow the links too... so once you have the source, you need to parse it. You can then insert the links' content (like CSS or script) in the original DOM.

Answer (score 0):

HTML can be messy. In the past I've used [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to parse HTML and generate XML in the form of a stream of SAX events, and then used [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) to build an in-memory DOM-like tree version of the XML, which worked well. Then you can use other libraries like [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) to execute xpath, xslt or xquery against that XML tree.

Comment: Its actually to pull some URL from the Hypem site, however it regens the dom from  a plugin, so i need to get the new tree. Seems like the only way to get it is from chrome directly.

Comment: I'd check to see if the URL comes in the initial page load or from some AJAX call. You can use the network tab in the Developer Tools that come up when you click "inspect element" to see AJAX requests and the HTML/JSON/whatever responses coming back. You might be able to make a small HTTP request that mimics the AJAX request to get the information directly from the site without a browser being involved.